# Android: Is it guaranteed that Dialog's onCancel will be called before onDismiss?

Tags: android, dialog

By testing my implementation, I was able to determine that in my case, when both `onCancelListener` and `onDismissListener` Dialog callbacks are registered, `onCancel` is called before `onDismiss`.

However, as far as I can tell, the Android API is unclear (again) about this and I can only assume it's an API documentation defect.  Does anyone know if this is officially documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Dialog.java code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java), yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, code is not a contract, and is not much better than relying on results from testing the behavior of a particular API implementation.